# ¿Cómo puedo crear una llave pública y otra privada con RSA, pycryptodome?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encriptación

Cómo puedo crear una llave pública y otra privada con RSA, pycryptodome y tambien encriptar palabras.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey  import  RSA
import Crypto

key = RSA . generate ( 2048 )
encrypted_key = key.export_key ( passphrase = secret_code , pkcs = 8 ,
                                 protection = "scryptAndAES128-CBC" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Generar la pareja de claves RSA ya lo estás haciendo, en tu código solo falta definir la variable `secret_code`, contraseña usada para proteger la propia clave privada RSA. Por norma general queremos obtener la clave pública por separado no obstante.

Para mostrar la creación básica de las claves, así como la codificación de cadenas voy a crear ejemplos reproducibles con comentarios para ir explicando cada paso:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

#########################################################
#                GENERACIÓN DE LA CLAVE                 #
#########################################################

# Generar pareja de claves RSA de 2048 bits de longitud
key = RSA.generate(2048)

# Passphrase para encriptar la clave privada
secret_code = "12345"

# Exportamos la clave privada
private_key = key.export_key(passphrase=secret_code)

# Guardamos la clave privada en un fichero
with open("private.pem", "wb") as f:
    f.write(private_key)

# Obtenemos la clave pública
public_key = key.publickey().export_key()

# Guardamos la clave pública en otro fichero
with open("public.pem", "wb") as f:
    f.write(public_key)
```

Con esto obtendremos sendos ficheros *private.pem* y *public.pem*, la clave privada (usada para desencriptar) y la pública (usada para encriptar y que es la que difundiremos):

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA



#########################################################
#                        CIFRADO                        #
#########################################################
# Cadena UTF-8 a encriptar
cadena = "Hola StackOverflow en español"

# Trabajamos con bytes, codifcamos la cadena.
bin_data = cadena.encode("utf-8")

# Leemos el archivo con la clave publica
with open("public.pem", "rb") as f:
    recipient_key = f.read()

# Cargamos la clave pública (instancia de clase RSA)
key = RSA.importKey(recipient_key)

# Instancia del cifrador asimétrico
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)

# Encriptamos la cadena usando la clave pública
enc_data = cipher_rsa.encrypt(bin_data)

print(enc_data)
# b'l;\xc7\x96\xbd\xb5:\xb8:\xf0\xdc\xa6b\xbd)\xf7xb4\xca\xf0~\x0b...'

#########################################################
#                       DESCIFRADO                      #
#########################################################

# Leemos el archivo con la clave privada
with open("private.pem", "rb") as f:
    recipient_key = f.read()

# Cargamos la clave privada (instancia de clase RSA)
key = RSA.importKey(recipient_key, passphrase="12345")

# Instancia del cifrador asimétrico
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)

# Desencriptamos la cadena usando la clave privada
dec_data = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_data)

# Decodificamos la cadena
cadena = dec_data.decode("utf-8")

print(cadena)
# "Hola StackOverflow en español"
```

Simple, pero no es así como se suele hacer... El cifrado asimétrico y RSA en concreto son ineficientes para cifrar grandes cantidades de datos. Por norma general el tamaño del mensaje a cifrar está limitado al tamaño de la clave usada. Un enfoque para solucionar esto es cifrar los datos mediante algún algoritmo de cifrado simétrico (como AES) y usar RSA para cifrar solo la clave simétrica, que es enviada junto a los propios datos:

```
import io
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP

#########################################################
#                        CIFRADO                        #
#########################################################
# Cadena UTF-8 a encriptar
cadena = "Hola StackOverflow en español"

# Trabajamos con bytes, codifcamos la cadena.
bin_data = cadena.encode("utf-8")

# Leemos el archivo con la clave publica
with open("public.pem", "rb") as f:
    recipient_key = f.read()

# Cargamos la clave pública (instancia de clase RSA)
key = RSA.importKey(recipient_key)

# Instancia del cifrador asimétrico
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)

# Generamos una clave para el cifrado simétrico
aes_key = get_random_bytes(16)

# Encriptamos la clave del cifrado simétrico con la clave pública RSA
enc_aes_key = cipher_rsa.encrypt(aes_key)

# Encriptamos los datos mediante cifrado simétrico (AES en este caso)
cipher_aes = AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(bin_data)

# Concatenamos la clave simétrica cifrada a los datoscifrados con ella
enc_data = b"".join((enc_aes_key, cipher_aes.nonce, tag, ciphertext))
print(enc_data)
# b'\x0f_r\xcd5%\x9a\x9bA\x14\xcdZ\xa9sl\'\x9d\xab\xea\xd2^1



#########################################################
#                     DESCIFRADO                        #
#########################################################

# Emulamos un fichero con nuestra cadena porque el método read facilita
# la división de cada parte de la cadena (datos y clave AES encriptada).
# Podríamos también obtenerlos simplemente mediante slicing de la cadena
data_file = io.BytesIO(enc_data)

# Leemos el archivo con la clave privada
with open("private.pem", "rb") as f:
    recipient_key = f.read()

# Cargamos la clave pública (instancia de clase RSA)
key = RSA.importKey(recipient_key,  passphrase="12345")

# Instancia del cifrador asimétrico
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)

# Separamos las distintas partes de la cadena cifrada
enc_aes_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext =\
    (data_file.read(c) for c in (key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1))

# Desencriptamos la clave AES mediante la clave privada RSA
aes_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_aes_key)

# Desencriptamos los datos en si con la clave AES
cipher_aes = AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
data = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)

# Decodificamos la cadena
cadena = data.decode("utf-8")
print(cadena)
#Hola StackOverflow en español
```

Comment: ¿Para encriptar a base 64 y decencriptar de base 64, es de la misma manera?