# Error al intentar desencriptar(RSA) mensaje

Tags: python, rsa

Estoy tratando de desencriptar un mensaje y cuando trato de abrir el `.txt` de credenciales me arroja un error que no sé como solucionar.

Creo que en esta función está uno de los problemas, ya que cuando intento guardado en el `.txt`. tengo las credenciales como `strings`.

```
def credenciales(pk,msj):

    f = open ('credenciales_crypto.txt','w')
    f.write('private_key : '+ str(pk) + os.linesep)
    f.write('msg: '+ str(msj) + os.linesep )
    f.close()
```

Con esta función encripto un mensaje y transformo el objeto `Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj` (`private_key`) en `string` y `mensaje` que es `bytes`, lo transformo también en `string`. Creo que el problema está cuando llamo a la función `credenciales()`, ya que si no los transformo en `string`, me tira error al guardar el `.txt` :

```
def encriptar_mensaje(mensaje):
    import Crypto
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
    from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
    import binascii


    random_generator = Crypto.Random.new().read

    private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
    public_key = private_key.publickey()

    private_key = private_key.exportKey(format='DER')
    public_key = public_key.exportKey(format='DER')

    private_key = binascii.hexlify(private_key).decode('utf8')
    public_key = binascii.hexlify(public_key).decode('utf8')

    private_key = RSA.importKey(binascii.unhexlify(private_key))
    public_key = RSA.importKey(binascii.unhexlify(public_key))

    mensaje = mensaje.encode()

    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)
    encrypted_message  = cipher.encrypt(mensaje)


    credenciales(private_key,encrypted_message)
    return private_key,encrypted_message


msg = encriptar_mensaje('SOY LUcAs458_001$')
```

Aca cuando intento abrir las credenciales, tengo entendido que estoy abriendo `strings`.
Cuando abro el `.txt` devuelvo una lista donde la posición [0] sería la `clave privada` y la [1] el `mensaje`.

```
def abrir_credenciales():

    f = open ('credenciales_crypto.txt','r')
    mensaje = f.read()
    f.close()

    result = [i for i in mensaje.split('\n') if i != '']
    result = [i.split(':')[1].strip() for i in result]

    return result
```

Con esta función intento desencriptar el mensaje:

```
def desencriptar_mensaje():
    credenciales = abrir_credenciales()
    clave_privada = credenciales[0]
    mensaje_a_desencriptar = credenciales[1]

    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(clave_privada)

    return cipher.decrypt(mensaje_a_desencriptar)
```

Y finalmente cuando intento desencriptar:

```
print(desencriptar_mensaje())
```

Me arroja el error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'n'

Porque no es el tipo de dato esperado.

Cualquier sugerencia es bien recibida

**Actualización:**

La función `abrir_credenciales()` y `credenciales()` las modifiqué para poder guardar `objetos` utilizando `pickle` y quedaron de esta manera:

```
def abrir_credenciales():

    with open('credenciales_crypto.crp', 'rb') as input:
        result = pickle.load(input)

    return result

def credenciales(user,pw):
    with open('credenciales_crypto.crp', 'wb') as output:

        pickle.dump([user,pw], output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Ahora el error en `desencriptar_mensaje()` es:

> AttributeError: _RSAobj object has no '_randfunc' attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error principal es que con `str(pk)` no obtienes la clave pública como crees. `str(pk)` simplemente retorna la representación del objeto en forma de cadena, algo así:

> Private RSA key at 0x7F53261402E8

además, a `PKCS1_OAEP` le debes pasar una instancia de la clave no la cadena que representa dicha instancia, esto hace que el código falle con el error mostrado.

Lo que puedes hacer obtener el certificado usando el método `exportKey` tal como haces en `encriptar_mensaje` y almacenar dicho certificado en el archivo.

En vez de usar DER directamente, otra forma más simple sería exportar la clave a formato PEM, que no es más que el certificado DER en Base64, delimitado por `"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"` y  `"-----END CERTIFICATE-----"`. A continuación puedes insertar el mensaje codificado. Si necesitas que sea texto y no binario (para pasarlo por email por ejemplo), basta con que uses Base64 para codificar el mensaje también.

A la hora de desencriptar puedes simplemente leer el archivo, usar `"-----END CERTIFICATE-----"` como delimitador entre certificado y mensaje. A continuación generas la clave a partir del certificado usando el método `RSA.importKey()` y le pasas la clave `PKCS1_OAEP()`.

El código completo sería:

```
import base64
import os
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP



def credenciales(pk, msj):
    with open('credenciales_crypto.txt','wb') as f:
        f.write(pk.exportKey(format='PEM'))
        f.write(base64.b64encode(msj))

def encriptar_mensaje(mensaje):
    random_generator = Crypto.Random.new().read

    private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
    public_key = private_key.publickey()

    mensaje = mensaje.encode()

    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)
    encrypted_message  = cipher.encrypt(mensaje)

    credenciales(private_key, encrypted_message)
    return private_key, encrypted_message


def abrir_credenciales():
    with open('credenciales_crypto.txt', 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
        pk, msj = data.split(b"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", maxsplit=1)
        pk = pk + b"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
        msj = base64.b64decode(msj)
        return pk, msj

def desencriptar_mensaje():
    clave_privada, mensaje_a_desencriptar = abrir_credenciales()
    pk = RSA.importKey(clave_privada)
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pk)
    return cipher.decrypt(mensaje_a_desencriptar)

pk, msg = encriptar_mensaje('SOY LUcAs458_001$')
print(desencriptar_mensaje())
```

---

No se exactamente que pretendes hacer, pero unir la clave privada al mensaje encriptado rompe todos los esquemas del cifrado. La clave privada debe ser siempre privada, valga la redundancia, y mantenerse a salvo de cualquier posible intromisión, si va unida al mensaje encriptado...

Una pregunta relacionada que muestra de forma genérica y simplificada el proceso:

- [¿Cómo puedo crear una llave pública y otra privada con RSA, pycryptodome?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/162038/15089)

Comment: Mi idea principal era, guardar en un archivo dos frases encriptadas, luego con otro .py leer ese archivo y descifrar los dos mensajes. Estaba siguiendo este [tutorial](https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/criptografia-python) y pensaba que para descifrar el mensaje necesitaba la clave privada, por eso la usaba como argumento. Gracias señor bot

Comment: Efectivamente, para desencriptar necesitas la clave privada como bien dices, mientras que la pública solo se usa para cifrar. El problema es que si almacenas la clave con el propio mensaje obviamente cualquiera que intercepte el mensaje lo tiene todo para desencriptarlo, por eso mi comentario final, simplemente me chirriaba un poco. Lo normal es que almacenes tu certificado en un archivo pem o crp (DER), lo usas para generar la clave como se muestra y luego lees el fichero con las frases o lo que sea y lo desencriptas con la clave.

Comment: PD: necesito conseguir esto: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335432/a-new-silver-badge-that-robots-simply-cant-win ... XD

Comment: Genial, acabo de probarlo y funciona, le podrías haber pedido esa medalla a *V.Putin*. Ya nos dimos cuenta en *SOes* que te fuiste a programar para él todos estos meses